# What's the difference between declaring a long variable with 'L' and without?

Tags: java

What's the difference between the following?

```
long var1 = 2147483647L;

long var2 = 2147483648;
```

(or any primitive variable declaration)
Does it have any performance issue with or without L? Is it mandatory?

Comment: `L` indicates that your `1` is type `long`. Without it is type `int`

Comment: If there is no suffix it is assumed to be int

Comment: You cannot use commas in integer literals; both lines of code are not valid Java.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the first case you are assigning a `long` literal to a `long` variable (the `L` or `l` suffix indicates `long` type).

In the second case you are assigning an `int` literal (that's the default type when no suffix is supplied) to a `long` variable (which causes an automatic type cast from `int` to `long`), which means you are restricted to the range from `Integer.MIN_VALUE` to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (`-2147483648` to `2147483647`).

That's the reason why

```
long var2 = 2147483648;
```

doesn't pass compilation (`2147483648` is larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`).

On the other hand

```
long var2 = 2147483648L;
```

would pass compilation.

Comment: making it `10_000_000_000L` will make it even *more* clear

Comment: @Eran Is the first option better performance-wise because there is no casting involved? Or which one is better if size is not a constraint?

Comment: @AbdullahKhan I doubt there is any meaningful difference performance-wise, but I'd still use the first option (will `L` suffix), since it makes it more clear to whoever reads the code that you intended to assign a long value to a long variable.

Answer (score 4):

For easy understanding each of the type have range in java.

1. By default every digit you entered in java is either `byte` or `short` or `integer`.

   ```
   short s = 32767;
   byte b = 127;
   int i = 2147483647;
   ```

So if you assign anything except from their range you'll get compilation error.

```
int i = 2147483648;  //compilation error.
```

[Type range](http://cs-fundamentals.com/java-programming/java-primitive-data-types.php)

And when you write **long** `longNumber = 2147483647;`

though it falls in **long** range but internally java treat it as

```
long l = (int) 2147483647;
```

you wont get any errors.

But if we assign beyond the range of integer like 
`longNumber = 2147483648;` we will get compilation error as

```
long o = (int) 2147483648;
```

here java will try to convert the 2147483648 to **int** but it is not in **int** range so widening error is thrown.
To indicate java that the number what we have written is beyond the integer range just append **l** or **L** to the end of the number.
so java will wide his range till long and convert it as

```
long o = (long) 2147483648;
```

2. By default every floating point or digit with floating points (.) are size of double. So when you write some digits with (.) java treat as a double and it must be in double range.
   As we know the **float** range is smaller then **double**.
   so when you write

   float f = 3.14;

though it falls in double range but internally java treat this assignment as

```
float f = (double) 3.14;
```

here you are assigning the **double** to **float** narrowing  which is not correct.
so either you have to convert the expression like that

```
float f = (float)3.14;

or

float f = 3.14f; // tell jvm  to assign this in float range by appending **f** or **F**
```

Answer (score 2):

If we don't mention the `L` with the value then value is considered to be `int` value.

It type casts the `int` to `long` automatically.